# Binding issue in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am creating todo list. I created the code using google research and I am getting the result. When I click the add button what i enter in text box is get added in the list (UL /li).

But by default In my scope I have two list it has to show by default before add new list.

here is my code.

```
   function todo($scope) {
    $scope.todo = ["Task1", "Task2"];

    $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.todo.push($scope.newlist);
    $scope.newlist = "";
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/5y4LsLey/1/)

Kindly bear with my english.

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question.

I got the answer I need to add something in the ng-repeat directive

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="something in todo" class="result">
        Hello {{something | uppercase}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you so much people